# str object has no attribute 'close'

Tags: python, text-analysis

Im analyzing a text for word frequency and I am getting this error message after it is done:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'close'
```

I've used the `close()` method before so I dont know what to do.

Here is the code:

```
def main():
    text=open("catinhat.txt").read()
    text=text.lower()
    for ch in '!"$%&()*+,-./:;<=>=?@[\\]^_{|}~':
        text=text.replace(ch,"")
    words=text.split()
    d={}
    count=0
    for w in words:
        count+=1
        d[w]=d.get(w,0)+1

    d["#"]=count
    print(d)
    text.close()
main()
```

Comment: Why are you closing a string...  --> `text=open("catinhat.txt").read()`. Maybe you need `with open("catinhat.txt") as f: text = f.read(); f.close()`.

Comment: @KevinGuan - If you're using the `with` context manager, you don't need `close()`, as that's taken care of automatically.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Ah, right. I don't know why I added `f.close()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't save a reference to the file handle. You opened the file, read its contents, and saved the resulting string. There's no file handle to close. The best way to avoid this is to use the `with` context manager:

```
def main():
    with open("catinhat.txt") as f:
        text=f.read()
        ...
```

This will close the file automatically after the `with` block ends, without an explicit `f.close()`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `variable` text has a type of string (as you are reading contests from a file).

Let me show you the exact example:

```
>>> t = open("test.txt").read()
#t contains now 'asdfasdfasdfEND' <- content of test.txt file
>>> type(t)
<class 'str'>

>>> t.close()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'
```

If you use an auxiliary variable for the `open()` function (which returns a _io.TextIOWrapper), you can close it:

```
>>> f = open("test.txt")
>>> t = f.read() # t contains the text from test.txt and f is still a _io.TextIOWrapper, which has a close() method
>>> type(f)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> f.close() # therefore I can close it here
>>>
```

Comment: so I need no close method at the end?

Comment: @M.gnus: see my update. You can not close a string, however in the 2nd example you are not overwriting the wrapper around `open()` to the file so you can close it.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> text=open("catinhat.txt").read()
> ```

`text` is a `str` since that is what `.read()` returns.  It does not have a close method.  A file object would have a close method, but you didn't assign the file you opened to a name thus you can no longer refer to it to close it.

I recommend using a `with` statement to manage the file:

```
with open("catinhat.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()
    ...
```

The `with` statement will close the file whether the block finishes successfully or an exception is raised.